# why is R matrix inversion and transposition the same, but matrix Q has different inversion and transposition results

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems, image-processing

$R ={\begin{bmatrix}0.9697253054707993 & 0.04804422035332832 &  -0.2394255308445735\\-0.01069682073773017 & 0.9878712527451343 &  0.1549063137056192\\ 0.2439639521643922 & -0.1476554803940568&0.9584776727467001\end{bmatrix}}$

$R.inv() = \underbrace {\begin{bmatrix}0.9697253054707994 & -0.01069682073773021  & 0.2439639521643922\\0.04804422035332829 & 0.9878712527451345 & -0.1476554803940568\\    -0.2394255308445735 & 0.1549063137056193 &0.9584776727467004\end{bmatrix}}_\text{inverse R}$

$R.t() = \underbrace {\begin{bmatrix}0.9697253054707994 & -0.01069682073773021  & 0.2439639521643922\\0.04804422035332829 & 0.9878712527451345 & -0.1476554803940568\\    -0.2394255308445735 & 0.1549063137056193 &0.9584776727467004\end{bmatrix}}_\text{transpose R}$

above **inverse R = R transposed**

consider Q:

$Q = {\begin{bmatrix}2 & 3 &  1\\5 & 4 & 3\\2 &3 &6\end{bmatrix}}$

$Q.inv() =\underbrace  {\begin{bmatrix}-0.4285714285714285 & 0.4285714285714285 & -0.1428571428571428 \\0.6857142857142857 & -0.2857142857142857 & 0.02857142857142857\\-0.2 &-0 &0.2\end{bmatrix}}_\text{Q inverted}$

$Q.t() =  \underbrace {\begin{bmatrix}2 & 5 & 2\\3 & 4 & 3\\1 &3 &6\end{bmatrix}}_\text{Q transposed}$

**inverse Q $\neq$ Q transposed**

Why isn't Q.inv() = Q.t() as with R?

C++ are same types well:

Mat Q is of type 64FC1 and should be accessed with Mat.at(y,x)

Mat R is of type 64FC1 and should be accessed with Mat.at(y,x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $R$ is an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix), whereas the matrix $Q$ is not. Note that the matrices $R$ and $Q$ are not similar by the usual definition of [matrix similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity).